We should like to vs. We would like to vs. We'd like to
ex1) We should like to offer our apologies for the delay to your flight today.
ex2) We would like to offer our apologies for the delay to your flight today.
ex3) We'd like to offer our apologies for the delay to your flight today.
What's the difference between 'should like to' and 'would like to' and if it is contracted as
in "ex3)", how do you know if it's 'should' or 'would'?

In the US at least, 1 is not used anymore, so 3 can only mean 2. In general I don't think 'd ever contracts should.

For the difference between should and would, see this on ELU  and this. Should often carries the implication ought to, so not appropriate here unless you omit like to.
